# Using Visual Studio Database Projects when not dbo

Tags: sql-server, sqlproj

I am a new user of the Visual Studio Database Project, and I am inching in.  However, I am not the dbo, and do not have all rights.  Does that mean that I am UNABLE to use this type of project?

When I try the Schema Compare, and try to update the target, it fails when it tries to execute the following:
 DISABLE TRIGGER ALL ON DATABASE;

Is there a configuration that would allow me to work without that level of permission?

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would have your own developer instance that you are dbo of to do your development against and when you wanted to deploy the changes to a database you didn't have permissions to you could generate a script using sqlpackage.exe and an account with these permissions:

https://the.agilesql.club/Blogs/Ed-Elliott/What-Permissions-Do-I-Need-To-Generate-A-Deploy-Script-With-SSDT

And the deploy script would be run by someone who does have permission to make changes.

Good luck using ssdt it is a super great development experience :)